# Maven : copy directory structure without the files

Tags: maven

How can i copy directory structure without the contained files in to another root directory?
For instance from:

```
root
  -> dir1
  -> dir2
      -> dir3

to:

another_root
  -> dir1
  -> dir2
     -> dir3
```

Comment: What would you like to achieve? Why do you need such a thing?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [maven-resource-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/) for such purposes like this:

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>copy-resources</id>
            <!-- here the phase you need -->
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/extra-resources</outputDirectory>
              <resources>          
                <resource>
                  <directory>src/non-packaged-resources</directory>
                  <filtering>true</filtering>
                </resource>
              </resources>              
            </configuration>            
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    ...
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

But i'm not sure if you can configure it the way that only the folders without their content will be copied. Apart from that you can take a look at [maven-copy-plugin](http://evgeny-goldin.com/wiki/Maven-copy-plugin) but it sounds like you are not going the Maven way.